# Google Analytics: Internal tracking

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a custom-made eshop (so I can modify any code if needed) and I have added a section in each product page named *recommended products*. In there there are 3 links to other products. Moreover there is a section like this in the cart page. Again 3 links to products.

So a user can navigate to a product either by clicking on a trivial product link, either by clicking on the recommended product link (both links can co-exist in the same page), or by clicking this product from the cart page recommendations.

My goal is to try and watch if this is actually working and if it's translated to sales.

I have found many ways of working on this:

- utm (not recommended)
- Google Tag Manager
- javascript _trackPageview()
- creating custom dimensions

I think that the most important tracking facts should be:

1. how many users clicked a link
2. how many users that clicked on this link finally bought the product, in comparison maybe to the total product sales

Which way should I follow, so that I can not only track the (1) but also the (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do both.

Via GTM -

- Create a - 
  Event Category : Click Links (whatever name you want)
  Event Action : href url of that link
  Event label : Label of the Link

Under Behavior in GA > Events > Look for "Click Links" Event Category

1) That is how you will track how many click events you have on a specific link.

2) You need to know what is the Goal URL (meaning after User clicks "Order" what is the resolving URL or is it a specific AJAX call? If it is a specific URL, you can setup a Goal URL for that specific URL, if it is  AJAX call you need to create another Event Category : Order Complete, with an Event Action that waits of a datalayer push event to happen which is when the user clicks "Order" than this Event Action will be recorded.